# No overload matches this call. The last overload gave the following error. Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'

Tags: javascript, angular, xmlhttprequest, jwt, angular-httpclient

I am trying to GET a HTML page from my API using Angular with JWT tokens in the header. But if I don't specify the text type the compiler spits out a cannot parse error (it tries to parse the HTML as JSON then), so I need to specify my response type.

Here is my component.ts:

```
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKENHERE'
    })
  };
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {


  }
  fetchDashboard() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/avior/dashboard', {responseType: 'text', this.httpOptions,}).subscribe(j => console.log(j));
}
}
```

I tried removing or changing the content-type to text/html without any avail.

---

My API Response:

`<html><head><title>Dashboard</title></head><body><h1>Dashboard works!</h1></body></html>`

Comment: Is the Content-type header correct? What headers do you pass in while hitting this API through a client like POSTMAN?

Comment: @NicholasK in Postman I only specify the Authorization header with the token in format Bearer <tokenhere>

Comment: `httpCilentModule` will parse your request by default so you will have to specify the content type

Comment: Also, why do you specify a Content-Type in a GET request? AFAIK that is only for PUT, PATCH, POST (requests that actually send data in their body).

Comment: If I specify `content-type:text/html` and remove the responsetype i get `"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/avior/dashboard"`. Is this a problem with my API? I will add the response in the question, gimme a sec.

Comment: @JoelJoseph I am using HttpClient and not HttpClientModule which failed me apparently before

Comment: @Christoph I dunno, I'm trying to get it to work

Comment: Use `HttpClientModule`. Also what is the response of your API?

Comment: @NicholasK check updated answer for it

Comment: There is no need to pass in `Content-Type` as a header, as per your previous comment.

Comment: ++ Use `Accept` instead of `Content-type` in the headers..

Comment: @NicholasK like accept: text/html? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes.. That way you tell angular that you are expecting a response of `text/html`

Comment: I tried it I get `Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/avior/dashboard`. It seems it still expects and parses json...

Comment: Hmm.. looks like your API returns plain text then.. In that case use `accept: text/plain`

Comment: @NicholasK I get the same error. I think I need to specify the responseType but the way I did it in the question is clearly not correct. How should I accomplish that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try the following on in your component to see if your call works to another website. The following should return the html of the requested page as a string. If this does not work with your API then perhaps the problem is not your code in the component, but the response your API is returning

```
const requestOptions: Object = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', 'Bearer <yourtokenhere>'),
  responseType: 'text'
}

this.http.get<string>('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular', 
    requestOptions)
        .subscribe(response => {
               console.log(response);
        }
);
```

Comment: Could this be left as a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: `No overload matches this call.` :/

Comment: I've updated my answer, to prevent the 'no overload' message @Munchkin . I've tried this solution in a sample project and it returns the HTML of the requested url in the console.

Comment: @NicholasK I've posted this an answer as it is a solution to the problem mentioned, and is a way to retrieve the HTML from an url, such as his API.

Comment: This actually works! Now how do I add the JWT Token to it and how do I make the retrieved content refresh the view?

Comment: You can add your token in the headers and add them to your requestOptions. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! And how do I make the retrieved content overlay the current component displayed?

Comment: You would need to load the string response in your html either by parsing it or loading it in a template. I recommend searching or asking a new question on StackOverflow as it is not directly related to your question @Munchkin

Answer (score 9):

I did it this way:

```
    getDivisionName(x: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<any>(this.serviceUrl + `/something/${x}/`, {
        responseType: 'text' as 'json',
      })
      .toPromise();
  }
```

Comment: responseType: 'text' as 'json' does the trick in case you do proper type restriction (instead of any) as well.